# Kernel panic when installing VMware ESXi on Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, esxi

When booting the ESXi 6.5 ISO image in VirtualBox I got a kernel panic.

`PANIC bora/vmkernel/mem/pshare.c:3241
[...]`

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a simple matter of giving the virtual machine enough memory, specifically 4096MB.

Credits: https://www.walled.ca/category/virtualization-2/

Comment: Didn't work for me, no matter how much memory I assigned :(